# Python stderr - fail to parse exception message

Tags: python, parsing, exception, flush

I want to parse the exception print so that not all the exception data will appear.

for example, I have the following exception message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\flow_development\console_debug_sample.py", line 52, in 
>       raise Exception('Exception occur')
>   Exception: Exception occur

and I want to parse this exception that only the exception message will appear:

> Exception occur

for that I use to code:

```
class Unbuffered:
    def __init__(self, stream):
        self.stream = stream
    def write(self, data):
        self.stream.write(data)
        self.stream.flush()
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.stream, attr)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.stdout = Unbuffered(sys.stdout)
    sys.stderr = Unbuffered(sys.stderr)

    raise Exception('Exception occur')
```

But, every line at the exception is calling the 'write' function separately, so I can't  flush all exception message and parse.

Any idea ?

Comment: Why on earth do you want to do that? Do you realize that you are hiding *a lot* of useful information? In fact, if you ever open a question on SO and do *not* provide the *full* exception traceback people(me included) *will* ask you about it. So, I hope you are doing this only because you want to experiment exception handling, not for real use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to change the [`sys.excepthook`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) function:

```
import sys

def my_hook(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb):
    sys.stderr.write('{}: {}\n'.format(exc_type.__name__, exc_value))
    sys.stderr.flush()
    sys.exit(-1)


sys.excepthook = my_hook
```

After this change, whenever an **uncaught** exception is raised, the traceback will not be printed and the program will exit:

```
>>> raise RuntimeError('ARGHHH!!!')
RuntimeError: ARGHHH!!!
```

---

If you want to replace `sys.stderr` in order to do this, then you'll have to check whether you are printing a traceback or not. For example:

```
class NastyStderr(object):
    def __init__(self, stream):
        self.stream = stream
        self.printing_traceback = False
    def write(self, data):
        if self.printing_traceback:
            if not data.startswith('  '):
                self.stream.write(data)
                self.stream.flush()
                self.printing_traceback = False
        else:
            if data.startswith('Traceback'):
                self.printing_traceback = True
            elif not data.startswith('\nDuring handling'):
                self.stream.write(data)
                self.stream.flush()
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.stream, attr)
```

Used as:

```
>>> sys.stderr = NastyStderr(sys.stderr)
>>> raise ValueError('A')
ValueError: A
>>> try:
...     raise RuntimeError('A')
... except Exception as e:
...     raise ValueError('B')
... 
RuntimeError: A
ValueError: B
```

As you can see in the second example it prints both exceptions that occurred. It would be pretty hard to write a `NastyStderr` that is able to understand that it should print only the second one.

However it is pretty simple to change the `sys.excepthook` solution in order to print all the exceptions in the traceback:

```
>>> import sys
>>> def my_hook(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb, exit=True):
...     if exc_value.__context__ is not None:
...             prev = exc_value.__context__
...             my_hook(prev.__class__, prev, prev.__traceback__, exit=False)
...     sys.stderr.write('{}: {}\n'.format(exc_type.__name__, exc_value))
...     sys.stderr.flush()
...     if exit:
...             sys.exit(-1)
... 
>>> sys.excepthook = my_hook
>>> try:
...     raise Exception('A')
... except Exception:
...     raise ValueError('B')
... 
Exception: A
ValueError: B
```

Comment: Thanks!!!! works like a charm :-) and how do I return sys.excepthook to the default value?

Comment: @EitanG There is a `sys.__excepthook__` argument that can be used to restore the default(like most other attributes).

Comment: @EitanG If you found my answer useful you should [vote it up](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). If it solves your problem you should [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can always catch the exception.
If you dont want to print all the message, just catch the exception and print your message.

eg.

```
import sys
class Unbuffered:
    def __init__(self, stream):
        self.stream = stream
    def write(self, data):
        self.stream.write(data)
        self.stream.flush()
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.stream, attr)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
       sys.stdout = Unbuffered(sys.stdout)
       sys.stderr = Unbuffered(sys.stderr)

       raise Exception('Exception occur')
    except Exception:
       print 'Exception occur'
```